# Delete just one session in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have create many sessions in Symfony 5.

```
$session->set('a', 'foo');
$session->set('b', 'bar');
```

Now I want just delete 'a' session.

With `$session->invalidate();` all sessions delete.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating "many sessions", but setting many values on the same session.

By calling `$session->invalidate()` you invalidate the whole session, thus deleting all values.

To remove a single value, just call `remove()`.

```php
$session->remove('a');
```